# multiple mysql_connect are closed together

Tags: php, mysql

what does happen if I use multiple `mysql_connect()` to the same mysql server? I use this function in some functions and call `mysql_close()` inside one of them and it cause the other connections be closed too.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: dude, you accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: and because of that use give me -1 point? we need to do multiple connection sometimes. My question was a question about connection concept.

Comment: It is not true. Your question was not about "concept" but about wrong connection usage in your code. For the code from your question you don't need multiple connections at all. Once you will need it - you are welcome to ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the mysql connection with an identifier, for example:

```
$connection1 = mysql_connect('server','user','password');

$connection2 = mysql_connect('server','user','password');
mysql_close($connection1);
```

this will only close $connection1;

Answer (score 2):

Just **don't use multiple connects.**
Connect once, then run your functions and then call mysql_close once (not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in which the `NewLink` will be stored.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

> If a *second call* is made to `mysql_connect()` with the same arguments,
>   *no new link* will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
>   the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter
>   modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new
>   link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same
>   parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
 bool mysql_close  ([ resource $link_identifier  ] )

mysql_close() closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL server that's associated with the specified link identifier. If link_identifier isn't specified, the last opened link is used.

Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.
```

Check this reference :http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: hello this is the useful content for this question ! why do you click as not useful ! it actually helps someone not for yours.